# CMake + MSys2 undefined references to everything (including c++ runtime)

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, mingw-w64

I'm playing around with developing a cross-platform C++ project. Things build fine on Linux, but on Windows (10) + MSys2 I've run into a strange issue. Compile works fine (picks up my include dirs, etc.), but linking fails with all sorts of undefined reference errors to a static imported library I have, and even the C++ runtime.

I've tried setting CMAKE_C[XX]_COMPILER, CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM, but the output from the configuration step is always the same:

```
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/MINGW64_NT-10.0-19041 to use this system, please post your config file on discourse.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/MINGW64_NT-10.0-19041 to use this system, please post your config file on discourse.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /mingw64/bin/cc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/MINGW64_NT-10.0-19041 to use this system, please post your config file on discourse.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /mingw64/bin/CC.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: <....>
```

As mentioned earlier the compile works, but linking the executable fails spectacularly. Here is my minimal working example:

```
$ cat ../CMakeLists.txt
project(example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_executable(example
        main.cpp
)
```

Here is an sample of the output (the rest is omitted for brevity):

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
```

Adding -v to cmake produces the following commands.

Compile:

```
/mingw64/bin/CC.exe   -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.obj -c /home/.../Development/minex/main.cpp
```

Link:

```
/mingw64/bin/CC.exe CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.obj -o example
```

CC.exe seems off... and it's used if I set the CXX compiler flag or not...

I also tried generating "MSYS2 Makefiles" but that also fails (doesn't know the generator).

I can reproduce the output by running

```
$ CC main.cpp -o example
```

while

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o example
```

works fine.

CMake version is 3.18.4.

Edit: This is the entire output of running `make VERBOSE=1` (using `mingw64-cmake` seems to produce the same output, except the 'entering directory' and 'leaving directory' paths are absolute windows paths):

```
    $ cat log
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -S/home/<...>/Development/minex -B/home/<...>/Development/minex/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start /home/<...>/Development/minex/build/CMakeFiles /home/<...>/Development/minex/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/<...>/Development/minex/build'
make  -f CMakeFiles/example.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/example.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/<...>/Development/minex/build'
cd /home/<...>/Development/minex/build && /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/<...>/Development/minex /home/<...>/Development/minex /home/<...>/Development/minex/build /home/<...>/Development/minex/build /home/<...>/Development/minex/build/CMakeFiles/example.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/home/<...>/Development/minex/build/CMakeFiles/example.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/<...>/Development/minex/build/CMakeFiles/example.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "/home/<...>/Development/minex/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/<...>/Development/minex/build/CMakeFiles/example.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target example
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/<...>/Development/minex/build'
make  -f CMakeFiles/example.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/example.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/<...>/Development/minex/build'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.obj
/mingw64/bin/CC.exe   -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.obj -c /home/<...>/Development/minex/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable example
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/example.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/mingw64/bin/CC.exe CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.obj -o example
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.obj:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_[.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_]+0x0): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.obj:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout[.refptr._ZSt4cout]+0x0): undefined reference to `std::cout'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example.dir/build.make:103: example] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/<...>/Development/minex/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/example.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/<...>/Development/minex/build'
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

**Solution:**

I was setting CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER wrong :/. I was doing it from memory, and I just did

```
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=... cmake ..
```

not

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=...
```

**However!** It's still weird that CC is used to successfully compile cpp files, but it can't link the object files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have these errors because you are trying to compile/link c++ program with a c compiler. For example the two undefined references you are mentioning are part of libstdc++. It is used by default when using `g++` but not with `CC`. If you want to use CC you have to add it manually `-lstdc++`.

The easiest way is to compile and link c++ programs by using g++.

For some reason the /mingw64/bin/CC.exe is considered as the CXX compiler and the working detection is skipped. to avoid the skipp of the working detection you can add `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)`. to modify the compiler it self you can set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` as explained in [CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_COMPILER) or set `CXX` as explained in [CXX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CXX.html) . be careful to clean the cache.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I convince CMake to use g++, since it's ignoring the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER variable? I also tried enable_language(CXX) with the same result...

Comment: can you add the output of `ake VERBOSE=1` to see what is happening? In my pc with msys2 and cmake 3.17.3 i see that c++ is used and not cc with the same cmakelist than you.

Comment: I added the full build log to original question.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out I was just using the wrong way to set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER, but your answer made me look at the docs you provided, so it refreshed my memory. Should I just have a toolchain file for mingw then?

Comment: Yes , a toolchain file for mingw would be a good choice.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `mingw64` compiler in `MSYS2` make sure you are using `mingw64` version of `cmake` too.

Using cmake not aligned with gcc e.g.:

```
MINGW64
# which gcc
/mingw64/bin/gcc

MINGW64
# which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake
```

Will led to following error when running cmake:

```
...
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/MINGW64_NT-10.0-19041 to use this system, please post your config file on discourse.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
...
```

and linker error in build step.

So make sure you install mingw64 version of cmake:

```
MINGW64
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake
```

You need to close terminal and open it again after cmake is installed. Then make sure you have aligned versions of gcc and cmake installed:

```
MINGW64
# which gcc
/mingw64/bin/gcc

MINGW64
# which cmake
/mingw64/bin/cmake
```

Now cmake should work properly.

Comment: "make sure you install mingw64 version of cmake"  That's one heck of a [footgun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/footgun#Noun).